# OpenCV - After feature points detection, how can I get the x,y-coordinates of the feature points

Tags: python, opencv, feature-detection

My process is

- first is to detect the feature points
- next, I want the x,y-coordinates of feature points in order to build a histogram to find the local density of maxima of x,y histogram

Any helps is appreciate

Following this example: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_orb/py_orb.html#orb

Comment: Please show your current code.

Comment: I added the link that I followed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
kp = orb.detect(img,None)
kp, des = orb.compute(img, kp)
```

The kp variable is a list of [Keypoint](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#keypoint) objects.

The `pt` member of this object is the position of the keypoint.

So, for example:

```
for i,keypoint in enumerate(kp):
    print "Keypoint %d: %s" % (i, keypoint.pt)
```

Comment: Sir, I tried to get the x and y-coordinate separately, such as: `keypoint.pt.x`. However the error shows that `there no attribute name x`. How can I define to use the x and y-coordinate information

Comment: @SangSam The `pt` attribute is just a Python tuple with two elements. Use `keypoint.pt[0]` and  `keypoint.pt[1]`.